# How do TaskInstances in the same process share variables in airflow

Tags: airflow

I have a requirement to get information from the current instance process in a running DAGs instance

For example, if I have created an DAGs instance [run_id] via the airflow API, do I have a way to get the global variables of this process group and define a method that is aware of the global variables of each DAGs instance to get the parameters I want

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to cross-communication between tasks you can use [Xcom](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/xcoms.html#xcoms)
Note that xcom is used to share metadata and are limited in size.

Airflow also offer [Variables](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/variables.html) as key/value store.

Comment: Thanks, but For example, if I have created an DAGs instance [run_id] via the airflow API, do I have a way to get the global variables of this process group and define a method that is aware of the global variables of each DAGs instance to get the parameters I want

Comment: Not sure that I follow. what are global variables? when you create DAGRun by API you pass parameters. Why would another DAG be interested in parameters that you set for another DAG in a specific DAGRun? That sound a weird design of a process.

Comment: Maybe I have not described my problem properly. 
When I create multiple Task instances, can I obtain the information of the currently executed Task Instance, such as task_id. I want to create a function to get parameters [ such as task_id ] for each Task Instance.
Since each Task Instance belongs to a process group, functions in that process group should be able to share information.
I am not aware that Airflow.models.taskinstance has the func to do so